# Symfony redirect to a route after service logic

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I get an Access Token from a social network help with HWIO Bundle and to redirect after service is called. I tried adding router to the service:

```
<argument type="service" id="router" />
```

```php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserProvider implements OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $serviceProvider = $service."Provider";

        $user = $this->$serviceProvider->setUserData($user, $response);
        $grabProject = $this->grabProject->grabProject($response->getAccessToken(), $user);

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('application_frontend_default_index'));
     }
```

after my action I turn in controller HWIO Bundle in connectServiceAction

```
public function connectServiceAction(Request $request, $service)
{
```

Maybe need overwrite this controller and action, how to make this?

Comment: Please paste us the code of where your `connect` method is used. Also, it is usually a bad practice to generate Repsonses in services, this is the Controller's role to redirect of return Responses.

Comment: I update question? maybe need overwrite this action?

Answer (score 0):

The controller does not redirect because you did not `return` the `RedirectResponse` returned by your method when it is called. If you want a quick fix to make it work, just replace:

```
$this->container->get('hwi_oauth.account.connector')->connect($currentUser, $userInformation);
```

by:

```
return $this->container->get('hwi_oauth.account.connector')->connect($currentUser, $userInformation);
```

However, as I told you in my comment: this should not be your service's responsibility to redirect. You should do that in your Controller, right after your `connect` call.